# jQuery: replace If this HREF contains

Tags: jquery, replace, hyperlink

I'd like to replace an affiliate link with another using jQuery. I want to find all links which *start* with `redirect.affiliatelink1.com` and replace it with `api.affiliatelink2.com`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.post-body-inner a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is('[href$=redirect.affiliatelink1.com]')) {
      $(this).attr('href', 'https://api.affiliatelink2.com');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues in your code. Firstly `$=` in the attribute selector is for 'ends with' matches. To match at the start of the attribute value use `^=`.

Secondly you need to replace the existing value, not overwrite the entire thing with the new URL only.

Lastly, you can simplify the logic by providing a function to `attr()` which is executed against all selected `a` elements instead of an explicit `each()` loop.

With all that said, try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.post-body-inner a').attr('href', (i, h) => h.replace('https://redirect.affiliatelink1.com', 'https://api.affiliatelink2.com'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-body-inner">
  <a href="https://redirect.affiliatelink1.com/foo">Foo</a>
</div>
```

Comment: it is working - but i want to replace all href content - my affiliate links looks like "redirect.affiliatelink1.com/?utm_medium=cpt&amp;utm_content=affiliate&amp;utm_campaign=100" - and i want to replace all href content not only the main domain